Can I Embed an Existing ASP.NET Application Inside My New Flutter App to Access Its Services?
Is it possible to open an existing and functional application within my new application and access all of its services? Note that my application is developed in Flutter, while the other application is developed in ASP.NET?
I attempted to integrate an existing ASP.NET application into my new Flutter app to access its services. I expected the ASP.NET app to open seamlessly within my Flutter app, allowing me to utilize its functionalities. However, I encountered compatibility issues between the two frameworks, preventing successful integration.
